# How to get a book back from the numbered list?

Tags: java, mongodb

As you can see, I'm trying to get a book back from a numbered list of books that I created in MongoDB.  I am getting the books back fine from the database, but when I try to pull out the number from which the book is listed, I can't because of this line:

bookNum = book.get(choice - 1);

The code I have is listed below for your help.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//Find a book in the bookInfo database
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the Title of a Book: ");
    String book = input.nextLine();
    int referenceNum = 0;
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("Title", 
            new BasicDBObject("$regex", book)
            .append("$options", "i"));
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query).iterator();

    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document bookInfo = cursor.next();
        referenceNum++;
        System.out.println(referenceNum + ")" + bookInfo.getString("Title"));

    }
    System.out.print("\nEnter selection number (0 to quit): ");
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = inp.nextInt();
    String bookNum;
    // choice not 0 and not too high
    if(choice > 0 && choice <= referenceNum) {
        bookNum = book.get(choice - 1);
    }
    else {
        bookNum = "0";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:** The list of books fetched from the DB are not stored anywhere

Following is the updated code:

```
// Find a book in the bookInfo database
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the Title of a Book: ");
String book = input.nextLine();
int referenceNum = 0;
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Title", new BasicDBObject("$regex", book).append("$options", "i"));
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query).iterator();
List<String> books = new ArrayList<>();

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    Document bookInfo = cursor.next();
    referenceNum++;
    System.out.println(referenceNum + ")" + bookInfo.getString("Title"));
    books.add(bookInfo.getString("Title"));
}

System.out.print("\nEnter selection number (0 to quit): ");
int choice = input.nextInt();
String bookNum;

// choice not 0 and not too high
if (choice > 0 && choice <= referenceNum) {
    bookNum = books.get(choice - 1);
} else {
    bookNum = "0";
}

// Closing the scanner
input.close();
```